# Objective-C: Mouse location on IBAction

Tags: objective-c, mouseevent

I have an IBAction which should, when activated, wait until the mouse is clicked and then print the location. How do I do that properly? My attempt:

```
BOOL finished = NO;
while (!finished) {
    if ([NSEvent pressedMouseButtons] == 1) {
        finished = YES;
        NSLog(@"%f | %f", [NSEvent mouseLocation].x, [NSEvent mouseLocation].y);
    }
}
```

does work but will show a busy mouse pointer. So I guess there must be a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

Both the IBaction and Click events occur on a Main Thread only.  It seems you are blocking the main thread with a while loop in IBAction  until the mouse click happens, which is like putting the Main thread busy.

You should run this while loop in a secondary thread so that Main thread will be free of this while loop checking.

Comment: Is there no simpler way to achieve what I want? Maybe without a while loop?